# Error on first query in first lesson: "There should be a title property in your query"

Tags: neo4j

I am on the [first lesson](https://neo4j.com/graphacademy/online-training/getting-started-graph-databases-using-neo4j/part-1/) in Getting Started with Graph Databases using Neo4j – Part 1 Introduction.
I entered:

```
match (:Person)-[r :ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)
return r.roles
```

I get a resultset back, but there is also an error message in red, "There should be a title property in your query".  Googling find lots of examples that include a property named 'Title', but that does not seem relevant to this error.  Does anyone know what is going on with the message?

Answer (score 1):

Cypher widgets are exercices : there is a goal and you need to write the query to achieve it.

The first cypher widget is a just an example. If you look at the top of widget you should see `Adding 'Mystic River`, so it's what you need to write. 
And indeed for this example, the cypher query should have a `title` property.

NOTE: the screenshot and the live example are not the same.

Comment: That actually produces yet another error.  I'll just move on and figure this out.